# How to connect to old SQL Server (6.5)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledbconnection

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 6.5 database but I can not get it to work. As I understand, for this old version of SQL Server, OLE DB data provider should be used instead of Sql server data provider. (I tried that one also with same result.) So when I'm running the code below it throws an OleDbException saying that "the data source can not be used, because it DBMS version is less than 7.0.0."

So please help me out (google failed me on this one): How to connect to SQL Server 6.5? I'm using VS2015. When I tried to connect, I used the correct server, pwd etc in the connection string and not the ones in the code below.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conn = new OleDbConnection
            {
                ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=TheIP;Database=TheDB;Uid=hello;Pwd=world;"
            };
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kind of obvious question, but would upgrading be an option? This is software from 1996(!). Security updates are not released for years.

Comment: Try setting up an ODBC connection. Not really sure.

Comment: The problem is that I can not find any odbc driver for sql server version 6.5.